# Angular2-Seed + Typings + D3: Import error, 'Cannot find module 'd3''

Tags: d3.js, typescript, angular, typescript-typings

I'm trying to import [D3](https://d3js.org/) so that I can use it in an Angular2 module.

Some background info:

- I'm writing Angular2 in TypeScript.
- I am using [Angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

What I did:

1. I installed the NPM D3 package:

   ```
   npm install d3 --save
   ```
2. I installed the D3 type descriptions using Typings, as that is what Angular2-Seed uses for the libraries it already has installed.

   ```
   typings install d3 --save
   ```
3. Then, in my Angular2 module file, I added the import statement

   ```
   import * as d3 from 'd3';
   ```

The result is that TSC is giving me the error message *"Cannot find module 'd3'"*. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: could you try to download package from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-nvd3)

Comment: I installed it, set up the discreteBarChart demo, but it doesn't show up at all in the browser, despite there being no browser errors, no compiler errors. But before I'm going to invest much more time into getting NG2-NVD3 to work I'd better stop: NVD3 is not going to be much use for me as I need to build a highly custom visualization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if in ***package.json*** you already have a dependency for like:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "d3": "^3.5.17",
   ...
}
```

you then can go in ***/tools/config/seed.config.ts*** and add 
*'d3': '${this.NPM_BASE}d3/d3.min.js'* in ***SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV*** object, like:

```
protected SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV: any = {
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    packageConfigPaths: [
      `${this.NPM_BASE}*/package.json`,
      `${this.NPM_BASE}**/package.json`,
      `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/*/package.json`
    ],
    paths: {
      [this.BOOTSTRAP_MODULE]: `${this.APP_BASE}${this.BOOTSTRAP_MODULE}`,
      '@angular/core': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js`,
      '@angular/common': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js`,
      '@angular/compiler': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js`,
      '@angular/forms': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js`,
      '@angular/http': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js`,
      '@angular/router': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/router/index.js`,
      '@angular/platform-browser': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js`,
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': `${this.NPM_BASE}@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js`,
      'rxjs/*': `${this.NPM_BASE}rxjs/*`,
      'd3': '${this.NPM_BASE}d3/d3.min.js',
      'app/*': `/app/*`,
      '*': `${this.NPM_BASE}*`
    },
    packages: {
      rxjs: { defaultExtension: false }
    }
```

Let me know if it help. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what was missing. Before I used [Angular2-Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) editing the path and/or package variables for System.config() was a common step in adding most libraries, but I hadn't learned how to do the equivalent thing in this seed yet.

Comment: With the first release of final Angular2, the addition to the systemjs.js has to be the folder that has the d3.js installed in. To make it clear, you have to point to where you downloaded the d3, mine was in the same folder as the settings file, in the subfolder of d3 so the row looks like this.

'd3': './d3/d3.min.js'

in my case this is the last row in the map: object.

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the above answer helped for debugging my soltution - in that it identified it was a config issue, however using angular2@2.1.0 i had to update {root}/e2e/tscconfig.json (by adding:

```
     "types": [
       "d3"
     ]
```

as follows:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "d3"
     ]
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that there is a tscconfig.json in {root}/src/ as well. I updated in this and I still had a dependency issue with:

```
import * as D3 from 'd3';
```

in my component that through the error. Hope this helps at least one person!

Comment: Thank you for the up-vote. I opened a RFC for the typings to update their typings for d3, I got a response and submitted my changes, which they accepted - but I never built the test file they required.... so Im not sure if it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 5+

you can just do:

```
npm i -g typings

npm i d3@3.5.5 --save

typings install d3=github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/d3/d3.d.ts#6e2f2280ef16ef277049d0ce8583af167d586c59 --global --save
```